# Can my Azure web apps access the internal DNS of my Virtual Network?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have configured my Azure Web Apps and App Hosting Plan to connect via Point-to-Site gateway with my Virtual Network in Azure.  I followed this article here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/

I have a VM that is hosting DNS and my Virtual Network is configured to use this.

I want to be able to reference services running in my Virtual Network from my Web Apps via domain name and not by direct IP address.

It works fine if I connect using the VM's internal IP address eg 192.168.1.4. But, when I add a DNS A record pointing my-service.my-vnet.local to 192.168.1.4, my web app can't resolve the domain.

I attempted to check the DNS settings of the web app and it appears my internal DNS server is not one of the hosts configured.  Here's the code I ran in my web app:

```
from nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
let props = nic.GetIPProperties()
select String.Join("; ", props.DnsAddresses.Select(x => x.ToString()))
```

Is this possible to do?  If so, can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

From everything we have tried and talking with Azure folks at Ignite, Web Apps (point-to-site) were not designed to be joined to a domain.  That said, we are successfully using web apps to access on-premise web services using a binding with a **fully qualified domain name** (FQDN) and securing that traffic be certificate.

Comment: Are your on-premise web services accessible to the internet? And, their FQDN are in a public DNS?

Comment: No - the on-premise apps are only accessible internally or via the Azure Virtual Network. DNS is also private.

Comment: In the example I gave above, I'm using 'my-service.my-vnet.local' as a fully qualified domain.  This is from my internal DNS.  How is your set up different from this?

Comment: Same - but are your service bindings in IIS also setup to use FQDNs?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way web apps connected to a VNET works, you will not be seeing the DNS servers when you list all interfaces. If in command line you run the command:

SET WEBSITE_

You should see an environment variable that holds your configured DNS servers. If not, you should go to your web app in the Azure Portal, to the Vnet section, and hit the "Sync Data" button.